# how to filter nested array like this?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript, filtering

I am having response like below

```
 let m =  [
      {
        name: 'Summary',
        subListExpanded: false,
        subList: [
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'Upload',
        subListExpanded: false,
        subList: [
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'Tasks',
        subListExpanded: false,
        subList: [
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'Dashboard',
        subListExpanded: false,
        subList: [
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'Master',
        subListExpanded: false,
        subList: [
          {
            id: 'user-master',
            name: 'User-Master'
          },
          {
            id: 'menu-master',
            name: 'Menu-Master'
          },
          {
            id: 'entity-master',
            name: 'Entity-Master'
          },
          {
            id: 'vendor-master',
            name: 'Vendor-Master'
          },
          {
            id: 'xxx-master',
            name: 'xxx-Master'
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
```

If i search `m` the filter should be like this

```
 [
  {
    name: 'Summary',
    subListExpanded: false,
    subList: [
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Master',
    subListExpanded: false,
    subList: [
      {
        id: 'user-master',
        name: 'User-Master'
      },
      {
        id: 'menu-master',
        name: 'Menu-Master'
      },
      {
        id: 'entity-master',
        name: 'Entity-Master'
      },
      {
        id: 'vendor-master',
        name: 'Vendor-Master'
      },
      {
        id: 'xxx-master',
        name: 'xxx-Master'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

if i search `master` the filter response should like this?

```
[
      {
        name: 'Master',
        subListExpanded: false,
        subList: [
          {
            id: 'user-master',
            name: 'User-Master'
          },
          {
            id: 'menu-master',
            name: 'Menu-Master'
          },
          {
            id: 'entity-master',
            name: 'Entity-Master'
          },
          {
            id: 'vendor-master',
            name: 'Vendor-Master'
          },
          {
            id: 'xxx-master',
            name: 'xxx-Master'
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
```

if i search `xxx-master` the filter response should be

```
[
{
        name: 'Master',
        subListExpanded: false,
        subList: [
          {
            id: 'xxx-master',
            name: 'xxx-Master'
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
```

if i search `slkvcsmcskc` filter response like

```
 []
```

my typescript code is not working properly .please help me to fix this>

```
  m.filter(x=> x.name.toLowerCase() === search.toLowerCase() || x.subList.some(x1=> x1.name.toLowerCase()===search.toLowerCase()))
```

Comment: List all of your possible cases and program them out one by one and **then** try to shorten it. You miss pretty much all of your cases that you need to check. Make long working code that is debuggable and understandable for you and go from there.

Comment: Confirm  search 1) is to find character 'm' in a case-insensitve manner in the name property of array of objects... - do you do a deep search on the sublist as well and ignore ids, only search on name etc.. You have to be far more specific in your requirements.. Is it only on sublists you have ids?

Comment: Are you using a library like lodash.. Or just straight up Javascript array filter? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: is it possible for my last case

Answer (score 1):

The following code gives the desired output. Note that I added some complexity which may not be needed for your use case. However, the example should work for lists with arbitrary deep nesting (see 'bar' example).

```js
let m =  [
      {
        name: 'Summary',
        subListExpanded: false,
        subList: [
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'Upload',
        subListExpanded: false,
        subList: [
          {
            name: 'foo',
            subList: [
              {
                name: 'bar',
              }
            ],
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'Tasks',
        subListExpanded: false,
        subList: [
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'Dashboard',
        subListExpanded: false,
        subList: [
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'Master',
        subListExpanded: false,
        subList: [
          {
            id: 'user-master',
            name: 'User-Master'
          },
          {
            id: 'menu-master',
            name: 'Menu-Master'
          },
          {
            id: 'entity-master',
            name: 'Entity-Master'
          },
          {
            id: 'vendor-master',
            name: 'Vendor-Master'
          },
          {
            id: 'xxx-master',
            name: 'xxx-Master'
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
    
    
function search (input, query) {
  const queryReg = new RegExp(query, 'i');
  
  function searchInternal (data) {
    let result = [];

    data.forEach(item => {
      const parentMatch = queryReg.test(item.name);
      let subMatch = false;
   
      if (item.subList) {
        let subResult = searchInternal(item.subList);
        subMatch = subResult.length > 0;

        item.subList = subMatch ? subResult : [];
      }
      
      // push parent if it matches for itself or a child (list) matches
      if (parentMatch || subMatch) result.push(item);
    });
    
    return result;
  }
  
  return searchInternal(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(input)) /* create a working copy with JSON.parse(...) */);
}

console.log('master', search(m, 'master'));
console.log('xxx-master', search(m, 'xxx-master'));
console.log('m', search(m, 'm'));
console.log('bar', search(m, 'bar'));
console.log('slkvcsmcskc', search(m, 'slkvcsmcskc'));
```

Comment: Nice solution..  You knocked that out faster than I could.. Only thing I'd do is when you log it, do something like console.log('master', search(m, 'master')); so you can quickly tell results from one another.

Comment: @JGFMK Thank you for your feedback. I did as you suggested :)

Answer (score -5):

Actually it should go like this:

```
obj = {
    _id: "sjkd9skj",
    data: {
      dektop: [
                { 
                   x: 2,
                   y: 3,
                   t: { key: 'aabbcc'}
                }, 
                ... 
              ],
      mobile: [
                { 
                   x: 4,
                   y: 3,
                   t: { key: 'ffff'}
                }, 
                ... 
              ],
      print: [
                { 
                   x: 7,
                   y: 5,
                   t: { key: 'ppp'}
                }, 
                ... 
              ]
    }
}
```